# How to add AwsS3Client to spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I'm using `Spring Boot 2.4.1` and `Spring Cloud 2020.0.0` but I can't find `spring-cloud-starter`, `spring-cloud-starter-aws`, `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` where is this starters? 
How can I add these dependencies to my project? 
I need to get `AwsS3Client` in my spring-boot project.

Comment: add these dependencies directly to your pom or gradle build file?

Answer (score 1):

You can include below dependencies into your project i.e. pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: but where are these dependencies in the latest version of spring cloud?

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that you are using maven, if that is the case then, you can add following inside your pom.xml file;

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>    <!-- test is optional, it is based on your requirements -->
</dependencies>
```